# jquery result live filter working with table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First I must admit that I am really bad with JS or Jquery is that matters. I searched for code that would help me filter through results using jquery. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){  
        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero        
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;         
        // Loop through the comment list      
        $(".commentlist li").each(function(){           
            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out    
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {     
                $(this).fadeOut();  
                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {     
                $(this).show();     
                count++;         
            }        
        });        
        // Update the count     
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = " + count);
    });
});
```

This code works with unordered list listed below:

```
  <ol class="commentlist">  <li>Comment #1</li>  <li>Comment #2</li></ol>
```

Now this code works pretty good with lists. Nevertheless, I have a table in my site which has 3 records per row. Each record (cell) represents user profile. I want this exact search functionality to work on table so that user can type username and it would bring it up. Is that possible?

Thanks guys and really appreciate the support,

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#filter").keyup(function(){  
            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero        
            var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;         
            // Loop through the comment list      
            $(".users td").each(function(){           
                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out    
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {     
                    $(this).fadeOut();  
                    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } else {     
                    $(this).show();     
                    count++;         
                }        
            });        
            // Update the count     
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("msg" + count);
        });
    });
</script>
```